# Vue Application : Footer doesn't render and give my 2 errors and warning

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I am kind of revising and trying VUE 3
I created a Task Tracker application. The problem is when I try to add a footer, it does not work and give me the following problems :

Also, it worth mention that I tried to add Vue-router before adding the Footer. So I removed Vue-router settings and files but still the same error and warning

```
Error : Uncaught (in promise) RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded


Warning : runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:6568 [Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of scheduler flush. This is likely a Vue internals bug. Please open an issue at https://new-issue.vuejs.org/?repo=vuejs/vue-next 
  at <Footer> 
  at <Footer> 
  at <Footer> 
  at <Footer> 
  at <Footer> 
and so on for a long line 


Error: Uncaught (in promise) RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

and here is my full code repo :
https://github.com/Ahmed-Elbessfy/vue-task-tracker-issue

Answer (score 2):

You are calling the Footer component inside the Footer component:

*src/components/Footer.vue*

```html
<template>
  <Footer>
...
```

use the built-in HTML `<footer>` element instead (lower case f)

Comment: Good notice. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

As @tauzN points, **you're creating an infinite loop** by calling the component Footer inside Footer.

You should use a multi-word name approach for your components:

> This prevents conflicts with existing and future HTML elements, since all HTML elements are a single word.

You can read more at https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Multi-word-component-names-essential